# Getting information from a View Controller to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

The scenario is as follows:

I have a view controller that analyses input sounds. Once a sound is recognised, I set a local notification like so.

```
var notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.0)
notification.alertTitle = knn as String
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

This calls the `application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)` function in AppDelegate.

Now, I also want to save some data in the database depending on what the user chose in the notification.
My AppDelegate's `didReceiveLocalNotification`:

```
var state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
if state == .Active {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: notification.alertTitle, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    var correct = UIAlertAction(title: "Correct", style: .Default, handler: { (test) -> Void in
        //create a new sound in context
        var newSound = Sound.createInManagedObjectContext(self.managedObjectContext!, title: notification.alertTitle, zcr: vc.zcrArray, spectralCentroid: vc.scArray, spectralFlatness: vc.sfArray, mfcc: vc.mfccArray, spectralSlope: vc.ssArray)
        var error : NSError?
        self.managedObjectContext!.save(&error)
    })
    var wrong = UIAlertAction(title: "Incorrect", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(wrong)
    alert.addAction(correct)
    var view = self.window?.rootViewController
    view?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In order to save the values to the database, I need to grab them from the view controller. But I can't find a way to get them. I have tried using `self.window?.rootViewController` in order to try and fish the correct view controller but with no success. The variables I am trying to store are called `vc.zcrArray`, `vc.mfccArray` etc. in the above code.

My storyboard looks like this:
[image: storyboard]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your storyboard self.window?.rootViewController is the tabbarcontroller. You should get the presented view controller of the tabbarcontroller, which is one of the navigation controllers. And then get the presented view controller of the navigation controller, which should the view controller in which you analysed the sound.

/*** EDIT

Since you're using storyboard, try using this piece code (keep in mind you use the correct name for storyboard and view controller):

`UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *uvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:uvc animated:YES completion:nil];`

EDIT ***/

If the values that you want to save are [property list types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44) you can use the userInfo property of the local notification to send them along.

Comment: Can you please give a code example? I tried all the combinations possible and I still get nil. I also thought of the userInfo but it only accepts one list and I need to pass 4...

Comment: Userinfo is a nsdictionary which accepts arrays, so you could set your data  like this: `ln.userInfo = @{@"zcr": vc.zcrArray, @"mfcc": vc.mfccArray};`

Comment: Since you're using storyboard, try using the following piece of code for getting the viewcontroller (keep in mind that you use the correct name for the storyboard and view controller):

`UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *uvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:uvc animated:YES completion:nil];`